# Linux desktop notification of SMART failures

Tags: linux, gnome, kde, smart

Are there any notifications mechanisms for KDE and/or GNOME which read their data from [`smartd`](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SmartMontools](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/) to control and monitor the SMART features of yours disks. I think it comes with most of the common distros.

There are man pages on [smartctl](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartctl.8.html) and [smartd](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartd.8.html) you can look at for full syntax. smartctl is for configuration smartd is for getting reports and alerts setup.

[Edit: There's also [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/index.php/en/Home), which is a GUI front end for SmartMonTools and claims to "automatically reports and highlights any anomalies". Haven't used it personally though. Is that the kind of thing you are after?]

[Edit 2: After much discussion, (see below) we have concluded [Smart Notifier](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/smart-notifier)  is the most helpful tool in this situation. There is also a guide [here](http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/monitor-your-hard-drives-in-ubuntu-810-intrepid/) that includes some details on how to get it setup.]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that already, I've linked to smartmontools in my question. I want to get a desktop notification when a SMART event happens.

Comment: Ahh. Sorry. For some reason I didn't see that link in there. I just read smart.

Comment: Have you seen this - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiskMonitoring ?

Comment: All links from that page are dead I'm afraid.

Comment: After edit: yes, this looks good. I'll take a look.Thanks.

Comment: It's _almost_ what I was after, except that it does not sit in the system tray and pops up when an error occurs.

Comment: Some people are never happy =:)

Comment: Check out this - http://linuxappfinder.com/package/smart-notifier and this guide - http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/monitor-your-hard-drives-in-ubuntu-810-intrepid/ Planning on trying this all out myself when I get home. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: smart-notifier seems to be the way to go. Please add it to the answer so that i can accept it.